# WPF, keyboard focus being reset after updating ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, input

I have a ListView and I'm subscribed to *OnListKeyDown()*. If I get any Left or Right inputs, I do some processing, effectively recreating the ItemsSource of the ListView.
When I say "recreating" I mean trigering this:

```
OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
```

I noticed, that after this, if I press up or down, the focused element will be reseted (instead of being the current one, it will be the 1st one). I tried logging the state during the input event, but everything looks correct.

Comment: How does the `ItemsSource` change? Are you just adding or removing value or creating a new object everytime?

Comment: @Alfie Its fully recreated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `SourceUpdated` event to reset the focus to the `ListView` when it is updated?

Comment: @Alfie I tried something similar. However, note that the ListView is still in focus, the problem is, the next "down" press will jump back to the first item.

Comment: Update, I found what seems to be the cause of the problem. After I update my Items, I see that the AnchorItem of the ListView changes to null. I'm not sure what set this property (but it is protected).

Comment: So does it remove the selected item on the view?

Comment: @Alfie I honestly don't know at this point. At 1st glance (hooking into the PreviewKeyDown & KeyDown events) SelectedItem,SelectedIndex etc. Are OK. However, there is something else that is resetting this! The only thing I can tell is different right after updating my List, is this AnchorItem, but so far, I couldn't manage to reset it...

Comment: From what you've said I think its becasue your fully recreating the `ItemsSource`, this means that the selected item no longer exists in the `ItemsSource` as the list contains all new objects, some ideas of what you could do is stop recreating the list and just add or remove items or find the same item in the list and set that as the selected item as set that as the selected item

Comment: @Alfie thanks for your help! I finally found a solution for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fighting for a few days I found how to reset my keyboard focus. First you need to cache the selected index, then, once done updating, reset the selected item and also focus it.
This is the code snipet for that:

```
View.EntriesView.SelectedItem = View.EntriesView.Items[cacheIdx];
View.EntriesView.UpdateLayout();          
((ListViewItem)View.EntriesView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(cacheIdx)).Focus();
```

Thanks to @Alfie for his help.

Comment: Related: http://cytivrat.blogspot.com/2011/05/selecting-first-item-in-wpf-listview.html